# One formula to array month end with only 2 dates

Tags: excel, google-sheets

```
A1: I have 1/1/13
A2: I have 7/25/13
```

How do I, using one formula, in A3 so the output looks like this:

```
1/31/13,2/28/13,3/31/13,4/30/13,5/31/13,6/30/13,7/31,13
```

ie. In one cell, one formula gives me all the month end dates.

without code please.

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing this without a macro, or an exceptionally long, confusing, and repetitive formula.

Comment: i have faith in the stackoverflow community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this in a module:

```
Function myFormula(startDate, endDate)
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim result As String
    result = ""
    noOfMonths = DateDiff("m", startDate, endDate)
    For i = 1 To noOfMonths + 1
        Dim myDate As Date
        myDate = DateAdd("d", Day(startDate) - 1, startDate)
        myDate = DateAdd("m", i, myDate)
        myDate = DateAdd("d", -1, myDate)
        result = result & Format(myDate, "m\/d\/yy")
        If i <= noOfMonths Then result = result & ","
    Next i
    myFormula = result
ex:
    Exit Function
err:
    MsgBox (err.Number & err.Description)
    myFormula = "Error"
    Resume ex
End Function
```

and this in A3: **=myFormula(A1;A2)**

Comment: Alan thanks for the code, but is it possible without code?

Comment: I always try to do things without code first... it is possible, but not feasible in one single formula in one single cell...

Comment: i just figured it out... google spreadsheet solution `=join(",",ArrayFormula(eomonth($A$1,row(indirect("C1:C"&month(A2)-month(A1)+1) )-1 ) )  )`

Comment: nice... sorry, I don't use google spreadsheets...

Comment: no problem. i thought the solution might be available in excel so i tagged it such. but i think it needs the `join()` function which excel does not have